# using vue instant search data in laravel blade route

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i'm new to vue i'm trying to use id from vue data in laravel route in my blade but it's not working any idea why

```
<my-results>
    <template slot-scope="{ result }">
        <div>
            <h1><a href="/reports/result.id"><ais-highlight :result="result" attribute-name="name"></ais-highlight></a></h1>     

                <h4>@{{ result.id }}</h4>

        </div>
    </template>
</my-results>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how i fixed it thanks @GoogleMac

```
 <a :href="'/reports/'+ result.id">
            <ais-highlight :result="result" attribute-name="name"></ais-highlight>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! The JavaScript doesn't know to run in there though, so you'll probably want to bind the href attribute to either a data property, a function, or a computed property.

```
<my-results>
    <template slot-scope="{ result }">
        <div>

            <h1>
                <a :href="resultUrl(result.id)">
                    <ais-highlight :result="result" attribute-name="name"></ais-highlight>
                </a>
            </h1>

            <h4>@{{ result.id }}</h4>
        </div>
    </template>
</my-results>
```

Here's an example of a function:

```
resultUrl(id) {
    return '/reports/' + id;
}
```

You'll notice I put a colon in front of the href attribute, which is short for v-bind:href.